# SignalR 2.2.0 and SignalRjs 2.2.0 fail when stating connection: Client version 1.5, server version 1.2

Tags: javascript, .net, signalr

I have this call to connect to signalr in my javascript client:

```
 $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    console.log("Now connected, connection ID=" + $.connection.hub.id);
    connectionId = $.connection.hub.id;
}).fail(function (error) {
    console.log('Invocation of start failed. Error: ' + error);
});
```

It was working normally for a long time, but now I am getting this error message:

> Invocation of start failed. Error: Error: You are using a version of the client that isn't compatible with the server. Client version 1.5, server version 1.2.

I am using both SignalR 2.2.0 and SignalR.JS 2.2.0

**Update:**
The error occurred after the addition of this tag and we need this for azure:

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
          <rule name="StaticContent">
              <action type="Rewrite" url="{REQUEST_URI}"/>
          </rule>
      </rules>
  </rewrite>
```

With this tag the returned protocol version is 1.2, however when it is removed the version is right (1.5).

Comment: Is this your complete rewrite block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try adding an exception to that rewrite rule in `web.config`:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="StaticContent">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="signalr/(.*)" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="{REQUEST_URI}"/>
        </rule>   
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```